# Expanding mean over multiple series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a groupby object I apply expanding mean to. However I want that calculation over another series/group at the same time. Here is my code:

```
d = { 'home' : ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 
 'away' : ['B', 'A','A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
'aw' : [1,0,0,0,1,0,np.nan],
'hw' : [0,1,0,1,0,1, np.nan]}


df2 = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['home', 'away', 'hw', 'aw'])
df2['tie'] = np.where(df2.hw == df2.aw, 1, 0)
df2.index = range(1,len(df2) + 1)

avgcol = ['hw','tie','aw']
homenames = ['home_win_at_home', 'home_tie_at_home', 'home_loss_at_home']
awaynames = ['away_win_at_away', 'away_tie_at_away', 'away_loss_at_away']


def win_at_venue(df, venuecol, avgcol, name):
    df[name] = df.groupby('away')[avgcol].apply(lambda x:pd.expanding_mean(x).shift())

win_at_venue(df2, 'home', avgcol, homenames)
win_at_venue(df2, 'away', avgcol[::-1], awaynames)
```

How can I use `pd.expanding_mean` in a `groupby` object that will average over the `'home'` and `'away'` columns so I see their average wins/ties/losses over all venues? Now it just gives the prior win average for a team playing at home or away, not both home & away.

I've been trying different levels and df.stack() and reindexing but no luck.

Any help appreciated in getting there.

Here is what the correct result for just home wins at home and home wins all venues:

```
  home away  hw  aw  homewin_at_home  homewins_all_venues
0    A    B   0   1              NaN                  NaN
1    B    A   1   0              NaN                 1.00
2    B    A   0   0         1.000000                 1.00
3    A    B   1   0         0.000000                 0.00
4    B    A   0   1         0.500000                 0.50
5    A    B   1   0         0.500000                 0.40
6    A    B NaN NaN         0.666667                 0.50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to introduce a 'team' `column` to follow a team's record irrespective of venue. The below could get you closer. Starting with:

```
d = {'home': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
     'away': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
     'aw': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, np.nan],
     'hw': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['home', 'away', 'hw', 'aw'])
df.index = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df.index.name = 'game'
```

To get:

```
  home away  hw  aw
0    A    B   0   1
1    B    A   1   0
2    B    A   0   0
3    A    B   1   0
4    B    A   0   1
5    A    B   1   0
6    A    B NaN NaN

df.index = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df.index.name = 'game'

     home away  hw  aw
game                  
1       A    B   0   1
2       B    A   1   0
3       B    A   0   0
4       A    B   1   0
5       B    A   0   1
6       A    B   1   0
7       A    B NaN NaN
```

Next, stack so you can follow each team:

```
df = df.set_index(['hw', 'aw'], append=True).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3': 'role', 0: 'team'}).loc[:,
     ['game', 'team', 'role', 'hw', 'aw']]

    game team  role  hw  aw
0      1    A  home   0   1
1      1    B  away   0   1
2      2    B  home   1   0
3      2    A  away   1   0
4      3    B  home   0   0
5      3    A  away   0   0
6      4    A  home   1   0
7      4    B  away   1   0
8      5    B  home   0   1
9      5    A  away   0   1
10     6    A  home   1   0
11     6    B  away   1   0
12     7    A  home NaN NaN
13     7    B  away NaN NaN
```

Then, define what's a 'win', calculate overall record and apply `expanding_mean`:

```
def wins(row):
    if row['role'] == 'home':
        return row['hw']
    else:
        return row['aw']
df['wins'] = df.apply(wins, axis=1)

df['expanding_mean'] = df.groupby('team')['wins'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_mean(x).shift())

    game team  role  hw  aw  wins  expanding_mean
0      1    A  home   0   1     0             NaN
1      1    B  away   0   1     1             NaN
2      2    B  home   1   0     1        1.000000
3      2    A  away   1   0     0        0.000000
4      3    B  home   0   0     0        1.000000
5      3    A  away   0   0     0        0.000000
6      4    A  home   1   0     1        0.000000
7      4    B  away   1   0     0        0.666667
8      5    B  home   0   1     0        0.500000
9      5    A  away   0   1     1        0.250000
10     6    A  home   1   0     1        0.400000
11     6    B  away   1   0     0        0.400000
12     7    A  home NaN NaN   NaN        0.500000
13     7    B  away NaN NaN   NaN        0.333333
```

Since you have references for both games and teams, you could `merge` and `filter` to get your preferred layout.

Comment: thank for the answer, works perfectly. Combining the wins in a function was the idea I was missing, makes it all clear