# Groupby Pandas levels

Tags: python, pandas

Similar to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567349/expanding-mean-over-multiple-series-in-pandas), I want to split a dataframe by groupby and apply a calculation.

Now I want to introduce a new column to split the calculation over the dataframe. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'year' : [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001],
 'home': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
 'away': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
 'aw': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, np.nan],
 'hw': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['home', 'away', 'hw', 'aw'])
df.index = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df.index.name = 'game'

df = df.set_index(['hw', 'aw'], append=True).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3': 'role', 0: 'team'}).loc[:,
 ['game', 'team', 'role', 'hw', 'aw']]

def wins(row):
    if row['role'] == 'home':
        return row['hw']
    else:
        return row['aw']
df['wins'] = df.apply(wins, axis=1)

df['expanding_mean'] = df.groupby('team')['wins'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_mean(x).shift())

print df
```

Running the above will give the expanding mean over the entire dataframe. But how do I re-start the calculation for each new `year`?

I have tried adding `year` to columns= in the df declaration but it is included in `role` which is not desired. My gap in understanding is in the levels so any enlightenment appreciated.

Edit: desired result below

```
    game team  role  hw  aw  wins  expanding_mean    year
0      1    A  home   0   1     0             NaN    2000
1      1    B  away   0   1     1             NaN    2000
2      2    B  home   1   0     1        1.000000    2000
3      2    A  away   1   0     0        0.000000    2000
4      3    B  home   0   0     0        1.000000    2000
5      3    A  away   0   0     0        0.000000    2000
6      4    A  home   1   0     1        0.000000    2000
7      4    B  away   1   0     0        0.666667    2000
8      5    B  home   0   1     0             NaN    2001
9      5    A  away   0   1     1             NaN    2001
10     6    A  home   1   0     1        0.000000    2001
11     6    B  away   1   0     0        1.000000    2001
12     7    A  home NaN NaN   NaN        0.500000    2001
13     7    B  away NaN NaN   NaN        0.500000    2001
```

Comment: you want the expanding_mean per team and per year?

Comment: Yes. After that I take this and merge to original dataframe. I just can't figure out how to use the `level` to include `['year', 'team']` in the groupby

Comment: you can group by two columns with: `df.groupby(['team', 'year'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `year` to `df.groupby(['team', 'year'])` and add column `year` in code above `groupby` with changing `level_3` to `level_4` in function `rename`, because column `year` was added to index:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'year' : [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001],
 'home': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
 'away': ['B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B'],
 'aw': [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, np.nan],
 'hw': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, np.nan]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['home', 'away', 'hw', 'aw', 'year'])
df.index = range(1, len(df) + 1)
df.index.name = 'game'

df = df.set_index(['hw', 'aw', 'year'], append=True).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_4': 'role', 0: 'team'}).loc[:,
 ['game', 'team', 'role', 'hw', 'aw', 'year']]

def wins(row):
    if row['role'] == 'home':
        return row['hw']
    else:
        return row['aw']
df['wins'] = df.apply(wins, axis=1)

df['expanding_mean'] = df.groupby(['team', 'year'])['wins'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_mean(x).shift())
```

```
print df

    game team  role  hw  aw  year  wins  expanding_mean
0      1    A  home   0   1  2000     0             NaN
1      1    B  away   0   1  2000     1             NaN
2      2    B  home   1   0  2000     1        1.000000
3      2    A  away   1   0  2000     0        0.000000
4      3    B  home   0   0  2000     0        1.000000
5      3    A  away   0   0  2000     0        0.000000
6      4    A  home   1   0  2000     1        0.000000
7      4    B  away   1   0  2000     0        0.666667
8      5    B  home   0   1  2001     0             NaN
9      5    A  away   0   1  2001     1             NaN
10     6    A  home   1   0  2001     1        1.000000
11     6    B  away   1   0  2001     0        0.000000
12     7    A  home NaN NaN  2001   NaN        1.000000
13     7    B  away NaN NaN  2001   NaN        0.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I had also tried what you suggested but hadn't changed to `level_4`. How do I know what levels represent what groups? Is there a way to view them?

Comment: It depends of number levels of multiindex. First you have one level and then append next three - together it is four.

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` both `year` and `team` and use `transform`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


d = {
    'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001],
    'team': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
    'value': [1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df['mean_per_team_and_year'] = df.groupby(['team', 'year']).transform('mean')
print(df)
```